# Excel VBA: string comparison does not work

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to compare an activeSheet code name with simple string, but the result is always true. I debbuged that and the variables values are different.

```
Sub Button_Supprimer()
    
Dim a, b As String
a = CStr(ActiveSheet.CodeName)
b = "Sheet1"

If (a = b) Then:
    frmSupprimer.Caption = "Supprimer un matériel"
    'frmSupprimer.UserForm_Initialize ("Matériel")
    frmSupprimer.Show
End               
End Sub
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z77HD.png)

Comment: remove the `:` and the `End` should be `End If`

Answer (score 0):

The result isn't always true, it's just that no statement in your code is actually conditional.

The existence of the `:` instructions separator token should generally be forgotten and left for golfed-up minimized fire-and-forget code that you would run from the *immediate* pane (Ctrl+G).

By terminating `If {condition} Then` with a colon, you have made the conditional expression be just an empty instruction.

Without it, the code stops compiling and you get a "If block without End If" compile error.

The correct syntax for a conditional block of code is as follows:

```
If {condition} Then
    {conditional statements}
End If
```

Note that the `End` instruction is essentially a nuclear option for terminating the execution of the program; globals get reset to their default values, the execution context is terminated: rule of thumb, you want to let execution reach the `End Sub` statement and let the VBA runtime unwind its call stack normally: the `End` instruction stops everything dead in its tracks right there & then - and it's very, very rare that you *actually* need to do this.

Comment: Awesome @Mathieu Guindon! Great explaining! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BAMDeveloper my pleasure! Note that `If {condition} Then {conditional statement}` is also legal syntax _on one line_ (that's why the colon-terminated statement "worked", at least as far as the compiler is concerned), but the recommendation would be to always use the block syntax even if there's [currently] only one conditional statement. Cheers!